# Thymeleaf Email template with table and link not giving proper result

Tags: html, parsing, thymeleaf

I am trying to send an email using Thymeleaf template. My mail contain info in table form and in some cells I want link also. Below is my template and output. The a href tag is not giving proper result.

```
<html xmlns:th='http://www.thymeleaf.org'>
    <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <style type='text/css'> td, th { border: 1px solid black; } </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <p>Hi Team,</p>
            <p>Kindly find the details</p>
            <table class='table table-striped' align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='1300' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>Name</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>Flavor</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>OS</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>Cus</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>Loc</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>Env</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>Zone</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>Date</b>
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor='#C0C0C0' align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <b>Status</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align='center' th:each='value : ${values}'>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;' th:text='${value.vmName}'></td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;' th:text='${value.flavor}'></td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;' th:text='${value.os}'></td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;' th:text='${value.customerName}'></td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;' th:text='${value.location}'></td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <a href='${value.environmentURL}'>${value.environmentName}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;'>
                            <a href='${value.zoneURL}'>${value.zoneName}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;' th:text='${value.date}'></td>
                        <td align='center' style='width: 150px;' th:text='${value.status}'></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p>With regards,</p>
            <p>Auto Notifier </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The value for environmentURL, environmentName, zoneURL, zoneName is not coming properly. Please help where I am doing it wrong [image: output]

Comment: Please post your Java code

Answer (score 1):

Two observations:

**First:**

You should use single-quotes and double-quotes carefully. Take a closer look at the [Thymeleaf documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html), and you will see all the examples are like this:

```
<div th:text="${value.zoneName}">
```

Single quotes are for text literals:

```
<div th:text="${'Your zone name is ' + value.zoneName}">
```

**Second:**

Looking this example:

```
<a href='${value.environmentURL}'>${value.environmentName}</a>
```

This will display the literal value "${value.environmentName}" because that is what you have between the opening `<a>` and closing `</a>` tags.

Instead, you have to place your Thymeleaf directive in the tag as an *attribute*.

Also, your `href` element needs to be a Thymeleaf `href` element!

Cleaning it all up, we get this:

```
<a th:href="${value.environmentURL}" th:text="${value.environmentName}"></a>
```